# Use of shared library is good in c but same code is bad in c++?

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

Hi i have some doubt on shared library. i was going  on line tutorial on shared library  below is the code. please help me understand thank you a lot.

**ctest1.c**

```
void ctest1(int *i)
    {
       printf("I am in shared library");
       *i=100;
     }
```

**ctest1.h**

```
#ifndef CTEST_H
#define CTEST_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void ctest1(int *);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

**mytry.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "ctest1.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   void *lib_handle;
   double (*fn)(int *);
   int x=990;
   char *error;

   lib_handle = dlopen("libmylibrary.so", RTLD_LAZY);  // opening the shared library
   if (!lib_handle)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
      exit(1);
   }

 fn = dlsym(lib_handle, "ctest1");  //storing the address of shared library function
   if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
      exit(1);
   }


   fn(&x);
   printf("Valx=%d\n",x);

   dlclose(lib_handle);
   return 0;
}
```

**step 1** : created a object file using -c option
       **gcc -c my ctest1.c**

**step 2** :created shared library using -shared option 
       **gcc -shared -libmylibrary.so ctest1.c**

**step 3** : compiling my main source code  i.e mytry.c
         **gcc -rdynamic -o run  mytry.c -ldl**

**step 4:** **./run**

All went good with above code but i have some doubt please help me to understand.below is the list.

1. Why function pointer i.e fn return type is double although it is holding the address returned by dlsym which is void * ?
2. if i try the same code in c++ using below command

   **g++ -rdynamic -o run  mytry.cc -ldl**

   why do i get error as **invalid conversion from void * to double(*) (int*)**  how can i fix it ?

   **fn = dlsym(lib_handle, "ctest1");  //storing the address of shared library function**  this is line where i get error if i try in c++

Comment: Which line is producing the error?

Comment: fn = dlsym(lib_handle, "ctest1");  //storing the address of shared library function. This is the line in mytry.c if i try  it in cpp

Answer (score 1):

C++ is more strongly typed than C, so pointers of type `void*` are not automatically converted to pointers of another type. Therefore, if `dlsym` returns `void*`, you have to explicitly cast the result in C++ when storing it in `fn`, which is of type `double(*)(int*)`.

However, your function `ctest1` if **not** of type `double(*)(int*)`. It's unsafe to convert it to that. You need to change the type of `fn` to `void(*)(int*)`. Otherwise the conversion is unsafe.

The syntax to cast `void*` to a function pointer it is pretty ugly:

```
fn = (void(*)(int*))dlsym(lib_handle, "ctest1");
```

So it's probably better just to use `typedef`.

```
typedef void (*ctestptr)(int*);
ctestptr fn = (ctestptr)dlsym(lib_handle, "ctest1");
```

Comment: i tired with valgrind i din't find any error with it can you please say how it is unsafe below is the valgrind output    ==4854== 
==4854== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4854==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4854==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 796 bytes allocated
==4854== 
==4854== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4854== 
==4854== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4854== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Comment: @user3588044 Casting from `void*` to a function pointer makes me nervous because there's a big opportunity for undefined behavior to be introduced to the code, where any number of things could happen. However, if the return of `dlsym` returns a pointer to a function with a return type `double` and one parameter of type `int`, then it's a perfectly safe conversion.

Comment: @user3588044 I just reread your question and realized that `fn` is not the correct type for your function `ctest1`. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks one last doubt why i need to take function pointer  return type as double only  and really confuse here why not other type? isn't the return type of function pointer should be same as of the function address which it hold keeping coverity issue in mind?

Comment: @user3588044 You need to change the type of the function pointer to `void(*fn)(int*)`. It's wrong as it is.

Answer (score 0):

c code doesn't support polymorphism, therefore functions are searched only by name. 
but in c++ you can have a few functions with the same name, so types must be checked.

the question is what you think should happen when you return void and threat it like double?

what you really should do:

```
typedef void (*fnptr)(int *); //create a typedef for easy casting.
fnptr fn = (fnptr)dlsym(lib_handle, "ctest1");//cast dlsym return value.
```

note the signature of the function pointer is the same as the function signature.

Comment: polymorphism is irrelevant. Did you mean overloading?

Comment: @SHR Thank you  can you please say Why function pointer i.e fn in the above  in mytry.c return type is double not void ? although it is holding the address returned by dlsym which is void * ?

Comment: @user3588044 default return type is `void*` that's why the dlsym return `void*`, but it return a pointer to function and you should cast it properly, unless you want to ruin the stack. why is the return type in your code is `double` while your function is `void`? it looks like a bug to me, maybe it was changed and forgotten..

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe indeed, overloading.